# The Junit message (expected was ...) is not displayed in the console with logback

Tags: java, junit, logback

I use Logback with SLF4J (migrate from log4j) and when I run a junit test that fails, the reason why the test fails is not displayed (AssertionFailedError : expected is <> but was <>)

All other logs are running.

My logback configuration :

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="com.jle.athleges.logback.TrashFilter">
        <logger>org.springframework</logger>
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="TRASH_FILE_APPENDER"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/logback_trash.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>logs/trash.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework">
    <appender-ref ref="TRASH_FILE_APPENDER" />
</logger>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="TRASH_FILE_APPENDER" />
</root>
```

My Unit Test :

```
    @Test
public void getAllMembers() {
    log.debug("Start getAllMember");

    long sizeBefore = repository.count();
    Member a = new Member();
    a.setFirstname("aaa");
    a.setLastname("hhh");
    a.setId(2L);

    Member b = new Member();
    b.setFirstname("aaa");
    b.setLastname("hhh");
    b.setId(1L);
    memberService.save(a);
    memberService.save(b);

    Assert.assertTrue(memberService.getAll().size() == 0);
    log.debug("End getAllMember");
}
```

As you see my service return more than 0 elements and my test fails. So, I receive this message :

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at com.jle.athleges.test.integration.MemberServiceImpTest.getAllMembers(MemberServiceImpTest.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at ...
```

With Log4J the statement was java.lang.AssertionError Expected <0> was <2>

Even if I use DEBUG instead of ERROR, the result is the same.

I don't understand why the part **Expected <0> was <2>** is not displayed

Thanks

Comment: Unit test output doesn't use a logging framework afaik. This is unrelated. Post your unit test code and we'll look at that

Comment: No, but in the JUnit view Eclipse, I think that I should see expected <x> was <y>. And in the console, the same. No ?

Comment: I switch to my branch without Logback (so usinf log4j) and when I run the test (exactly the same), I receveive this message : 
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<2>
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
 at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asserting a boolean:

```
Assert.assertTrue(memberService.getAll().size() == 0);
```

The framework just knows you want to see a true value, but not what the source of the value is. By the time the assertion is called, `memberService.getAll().size() == 0` has already been evaluated. Usually it's a better idea to use more specific assertions.

You could start with

```
assertEquals(0, memberService.getAll().size())
```

That would give you the `Expected <0> was <2>` output.

But I personally prefer the Hamcrest style of assertions:

```
assertThat(memberService.getAll(), is(empty()))
```

where both `is` and `empty` are static imports:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsEmptyCollection.empty;
```

This makes sure both the test code and its output are most readable.

Comment: Ho ! Yes you'r right. I change somewhere my test. Thank you very much. I'm alone, and somtimes I miss that I have under my eyes ;-)